# Is twice implementing an explicit interface to achieve "virtual" behavior an ugly hack?

Tags: c#

Ok, this arises from some discussion going on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726961/every-interface-explicitly-implemented-ioc-involved/25727200#25727200).

Imagine the following scenario. Company *Alpha* publishes library `Charlie` which exposes among others, a type `Charlie.Bar` that explicilty implements the interface `IFooable`:

```
 public interface IFooable
 {
     void Foo();
 }

 namespace Charlie
 {
     public clas Bar: IFooable
     {
         void IFooable.Foo() {...}
         ....
     }
 }
```

Now it happens that company *Beta* is subclassing `Charlie.Bar` in its library `Tango` for some very particular functionality where the explicit implementation of `IFooable.Foo` doesn't cut it. *Beta* needs to "override" the interface implementation and achieve a seemingly equivalent virtual behavior; Calls to `IFooable.Foo()` should resolve correctly to the runtime type of the object. Note that having company *Alpha* modify the implementation of `Charlie.Bar` is not a viable option.

So how can this be done? Explicit interface methods are marked in CIL as `virtual` and `final` so you can not override them. *Beta* came up with this "hack":

```
using Charlie;

namespace Tango
{
     class Blah: Bar, IFooable
     {
         void IFooable.Foo() { //Bar specific implementation }
     }
}
```

Note the implementation of `IFooable` again in `Blah` even though it is redundant. With this code, you actually get the same behavior as a virtual method when calling `IFooable.Foo()`:

```
 IFooable fooBar = new Bar();
 IFooable fooBlah = new Blah();

 fooBlah.Foo() // Blah's implementation is called.
 fooBar.Foo() // Bar's implementation is called.
```

Is this a very ugly hack? (I've seen it done in similarly justified? scenarios). What are the alternatives if any?

Comment: `IFooable` is not redundant here. This is called interface re-implementation. My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25008171/517852) has some explanation of this feature. One downside is that with interface re-implementation you don't get the ability to call the base implementation.

Comment: Does `Blah` *need* to be a subtype of `Bar`? If not, you could use composition: Store a reference to a `Bar` in your `Blah` class and forward all relevant calls to that.

Comment: Mikez is right. It is not redundant or hack. It is a [feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664594%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: The name of this in C# is [Interface re-implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664594.aspx) (link is to old spec). You can do it for implicit (non-explicit) implentations as well. It is not a hack, but it is a bit of a smell in my opinion. ***Edit:*** I see that @SriramSakthivel linked the very same page while I was typing my comment!

Comment: This isn't really the designed for use case, I think. Although you could end up this exact situation if Bar had not included the interface in v1 and you wrote Blah with the interface and released. Then Bar v2 is released with the interface and you update your references. So, I think, it is there to accomodate this situation if it does arise, but I would be skeptical of a design to do this specifically ahead of time.

Answer (score -1):

You're asking about opinions, right? I've been programming C# for 10 years. Yes, that does look like a hack. Not that ugly, but if I happened to have to write the Tango library I would try to isolate that code.

If I found interface re-implementation as solution to some design problem in my code-base where I control both Bar and Blah I would suggest that it is design over-complication.